# DELETE and PUT HTTP verbs work on all browsers now?

Tags: http, browser

One year ago it seemed that DELETE and PUT verbs weren't working on all browsers.

I wonder if it's safe to use them now in production?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RESTful services have been using GET/POST/PUT/DELETE in production for at least 5 years. Any browser that supports XMLHttpRequest will support PUT/DELETE in addition to GET/POST by definition.

Comment: Hmm..I wonder why Ruby on Rails is simulating DELETE and PUT with POST then. Is it because the HTML form only supports POST while Ajax supports all four methods?

Comment: Usually that's the case in older browsers, yes. PUT/DEPETE were simulated via a hidden field afaik.

Comment: Sorry for the temporal downvote, I managed to undo it. The answer is technically correct, "the best kind of correct" :-) However, it is a bit misleading: Safari versions below 3 for example supported XMLHttpRequest, even accepted the PUT and DELETE methods, and silently issued POST instead. It should be everywhere today, but there were versions of browsers that supported XMLHttpRequest without supporting PUT and/or DELETE. For this very reason client-facing REST services often offer alternative ways to get everything done with POST only.

Comment: The most important thing is that all modern browsers are supporting them :)